# Error ITMS-90035 - Xcode 6.3.1 [Invalid Signature]

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, provisioning, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to submit this cocos2d app in the App Store. Provisioning / code-signing configuration is done properly, however, there's a target, TexturePacker that is giving errors (more specifically - PackTexture.sh file).

[PackTexture.sh Path in Target Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3FK3.png)

**PackTexture.sh** represents all sheets created with Texture Packer, so if I remove it, the game will not function properly.

[Texture Packer Target Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cD3S.png)

Removing Texture Packer Target is also not going to work. I am out of ideas.

Texture Packer Target can be code-signed and provisioning info can be added. However, the provisioning profiles for distribution are not auto-detected to add them into that target.

How do I submit this binary to the App Store?

Comment: Do you have any other .sh file in your code?

Comment: Can you rename it? Maybe sh file is processed as a shell script and this confuses Xcode? (Just a guess, don't know exactly what is the reason)

Comment: @Nilesh, yes, I have .sh file in code. It gives that error.

Comment: I wish I could upload a screenshot, but do not have enough reputation points for this.

Comment: You can upload the screenshot to http://tinygrab.com/ & share the URL over here... I was asking like do you have any other .sh file apart from the "PackTexture.sh" file?

Comment: Thanks, I added two links above with screenshots. There's no other .sh file in project other than the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Texture packer command line tool used to build sprite sheet.

Install [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) software. Then open texture packer and in drop down menu, select 'Install Command Line Tool'

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report what happened.

Comment: It's done! I got the following alert - "Installation seems to be fine. TexturePacker is now available as command line tool."

Inside the PackTexture.sh file, I see the line: TP="/usr/local/bin/TexturePacker"

That's the exact location where I installed The Command Line Tool of Texture Packer. I even tried to link to the path where Texture Packer Pro is installed in Applications, but still "invalid certificate" warning shows up.

Comment: code signing is one another problem in this..may be your certificate is not valid..check it

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when deleted **PackTexture.sh** file from project!