# XCode Error itms-90035 - Invalid signature for GCManager.o

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

When I try to send my app to the App Store, I have this error:

[image: IMG file]

When I try to validate my code I have a success message.

[image: IMG file]

I didn't find the file `GCManager.o` in my project. I checked twice all App Store provisioning profiles.

Comment: I am facing the same kind of error did you find the solution

Comment: Keep searching. I do not find solution :(

Comment: Any luck, have you find any think?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859996/error-itms-90035

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found two solution for this error:

1. In XCode, go to the "Build Phases" tab of the Project settings.  Click on "Copy Bundle Resources".  Look for any files named "upload-dsym.sh" and remove them.  Clean and Build. Without the unsigned third party upload-dsym.sh files in your bundle, it is able to be uploaded properly.
2. In XCode, go to the "Build Phases" tab of the Project settings.  Click on "Copy Bundle Resources" check that there should not any code file like .h or .m file. This solution works for me.