# Uploading app to app store. ITMS-90035: "code or signature have been modified"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have yet another anoying code signing problem.

When trying to upload an app to Itunes Connect I get the following message:

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. Invalid signature (code or
>   signature have been modified). Make sure you have signed your
>   application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate
>   or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in
>   Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at
>   the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are
>   uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator
>   target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct,
>   choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the
>   Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please
>   consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html"

I have trued both through organizer and application loader, same error. I have created completely fresh certificates and provisioningprofiles, and signing the code in Xcode manually.
I have looked at this solutions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906564/xcode-error-itms-90035-invalid-signature-for-gcmanager-o) and the solutions linked from that one.

People suggest that removing certain script files, with "#!" and first characters should help. The only files like that i have, are Pods-resouces.sh and Pods-frameworks.sh, and I can't really live without those.

Also it semms that most people get a different variant of the 90035 error, saying:

> Code object is not signed at all

which is not the case for me, so I might experience a different issue.

Any suggestions to where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

If the build is signed correctly for distribution, you won't be able to run it. If you can run the build (the one you are submitting), then it is still signed with a development certificate. My suspicion is that its still being signed for development, since the majority of the various build settings will still have you building for development