# Error while submitting app to itunes connect: "Invalid Signature - Code object is not signed at all"

Tags: ios, xcode6, app-store, app-store-connect

Well, all was good with submitting to itunes connect, but out of the blue, I just got this email right after uploading my app:

> Invalid Signature - Code object is not signed at all. The binary at
>   path [churningseas.app/churningseas.codea] contains an invalid
>   signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a
>   distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development
>   certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are
>   correct at the target level (which override any values at the project
>   level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built
>   using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are
>   certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in
>   Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your
>   release target.

I've seen that this a commun, infamous error message, and that there is no clear answer to how to fix this.

Has anyone an idea on what could be wrong with my settings? Thanks you so much in advance, I'm suppose to release the app this month and I'm freaking out a little bit here...

Answer (score 2):

The email is asking you to check the churningseas.codea file. I had a similar issue except they were referencing a docset file in my project. After hours of debugging this issue, it has come to my attention that Apple is now frowning upon docset files. After removing the docset file it fixed my issue. You may want to check the churningseas.codea file and see if removing it doesn't fix your issue.

If that doesn't work check this answer [Error itms-90035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859996/error-itms-90035). There could be many causes for this error.

Comment: Hmmm, this is not a file, but a directory filled with lua scripts from Codea. I've been using Codea (http://codea.io) to program this app, I do hope Apple is not freaking out over this, not allowing me to submit a codea-made app to the appstore. That would be horrible...

Comment: They seem to be freaking out over lots of file types and adding new checks lately. Might want to contact codea about this issue.