# Can you give me solution for uploading iOS app error ITMS-90035?

Tags: ios, archive

I tried to upload my iOS app.
But there was the error.

I tried resign certificate, rebuild... but still happen.
I also tried the old source that uploading success before, but I can not upload.

I think, some certificates or provisioning are wrong.
Please give me solutions. Thanks.

```
ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [MyApp.app/MyApp] is not properly signed. 
Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. 
Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). 
Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. 
If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. 
For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error itms-90035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859996/error-itms-90035)

Comment: Thanks I will check and comment